# Can not read a file using in Xamarin forms using Pcl Storage

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I am trying to read a video file which is in byte array using PCL Storage. So I have added the video file in the folder named File using android studio tool. Trying to read from there. The thing is that in my code it can find out that the file exists in the folder but whenever I am trying to read it using the following code I am getting an exception: "Access denied" but I have already enabled the permission in android manifest for reading and writing from external storage

```
IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
IFile files = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync("myVideo.Mp4");
var text = await files.ReadAllTextAsync();
```

Comment: Are you using API 24+?

Comment: I am using API 25

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting an exception: "Access denied" but I have already enabled the permission in android manifest

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. You should [request permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=en-us) at runtime.

System permissions are divided into two categories, normal and dangerous:

- Normal permissions do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically.
- Dangerous permissions can give the app access to the user's confidential data.  If you list a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly give approval to your app during the runtime of the app.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider ... requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is categorized as [Dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous), so you should check this permissions manually for API level 23 and above.

## Update:

[Here](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) is an example that request permissions at runtime.